# Java applications show title-bar only with multiple monitors

Tags: unity, nvidia, compiz, java, multiple-monitors

I'm having an issue with Ubuntu, Java and multiple monitors. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. Java 1.7.0_80 (application requirement) and a laptop with a monitor hooked up via VGA.

The issue is when opening the Java application only a sliver of the title bar shows. It doesn't show the window or menu or even the title. It just shows 1-2 pixels worth of a bar.

The window isn't opening off screen. If I 'Alt+Spacebar' to try and move, resize or maximize the window, nothing happens.

The kicker is if I disconnect the monitor, the application opens fine. There is absolutely no issue running the application when my laptop has no monitor connected.

I believe the issue is with scaling, but I'm not sure how to properly fix this. I was tinkering with Screen Display and the scaling settings. It had four options, scaling using my laptop, scale using the monitor, scale using largest and scale using smallest. I was able to get the Java application to open once, but when I closed and re-opened it failed again. This is why I'm leaning towards scaling, but choosing any of the four options presented no longer works.

I see other similar questions with Java applications not showing, but I believe my issue is different. First, I do see 'something' opening. Second, the solution to the other issues doesn't work as I listed above. 'Alt+Spacebar' doesn't solve it.